# Using Microsoft Flow to send notification to powerapps

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate

I have a sharepoint list , I have a created a "flow" that says when a new item is added to sharepoint list send notification to my custom powerapps application.

My powerapps notifications are not going through. Below is my error message,

Action 'SendPushNotification' failed

**Fix It:**

> You should be able to fix this by verifying your account with PowerApps Notification. You may need to re-enter your password.

**Error type:**

> This action failed because the connection '-People Advocacy' is not authorized.

**Error Details:**

> The error message from the service is below. This maybe useful for support:
>   The client certificate was not provided.

Comment: Can you go to web.powerapps.com, go to the Connections section and check if that notification connection indicates that it needs to be fixed?

Comment: Thanks for response cherie. I dont see any indication that it needs to be fixed. connection looks absolutely fine